# How to dermine last item in containerless control

Tags: knockout.js

I am adding a row for each item in my observable array and want to underline the last row of the array.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<!-- ko foreach: myProductArray-->
<tr>
  <td><span data-bind='text: productName'></span></td>
  <td><span data-bind='text: productPrice'></span></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<tr>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td><span data-bind='text: calculatedTotal'></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I detect the final item from myProductArray in order to add some underline style to the td elements above the Total row?

Comment: pls fix typo on closing `<tr>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use knockout binding context `$index`.

```
<!-- ko foreach: myProductArray-->
<tr data-bind="css: {
  'cssClassForLastRow': $index() === ko.unwrap($parent.myProductArray).length - 1
 }">

  <td><span data-bind='text: productName'></span></td>
  <td><span data-bind='text: productPrice'></span></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: @SpencerVinco I believe, This is the best approach of achieving your need